# WPF DatagridCell Event Trigger

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, eventtrigger, datagridcell

I want to take Event Trigger of Datagrid Cell. I mean to say I want to write something like this

```
**<EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">**
```

and then call function this from XAML:

**void Cell_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)**

How would I do that:

i have this in XAML

```
    <ctrls:RhinoDataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Model.CurrentDataTable}"   
                             Style="{StaticResource RhinoDataGridBaseStyle}" IsReadOnly="{Binding Model.IsLinkFile}"
                             SelectedValue="{Binding Model.CurrentDataRow}" SelectedValuePath="Row"                                 SetAutomappingOnOff="{Binding IsAutoMap, Mode=TwoWay}" >
            </ctrls:RhinoDataGrid>


     <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource ActiveItemBrush}"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
```

Pls help

Thanks
Dee

Answer (score 0):

Check for "**IsMouseOver**" instead. I assume "**RhinoDataGrid**" inherits from our known WPF's DataGrid.

Comment: IsMouseOver - works only for style in XAML
I have to call that codebehind event so i can get Cell object

Comment: void Cell_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            } It should call this

Answer (score 0):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
              <Grid Mouse.MouseEnter="Cell_MouseEnter" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">       
                 <ContentPresenter/>
              </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: The event 'MouseEnter' cannot be specified on a Target tag in a Style. Use an EventSetter instead.

Comment: I ran the code above before posting it - it not only compiled, it hit the breakpoint in Cell_MouseEnter()

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing `EventSetter` with `EventTrigger`....

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}"> 
       <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="Cell_MouseEnter"/>
  </Style>
```

Comment: I have got error : The event 'MouseEnter' cannot be specified on a Target tag in a Style. Use an EventSetter instead.  Is there something special with my datagrid. I check online and for every one it works